# Eliminate blank lines in file read Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file into a list using Python. But when I do that the list appears with blank lines after each entry. The source file doesn't have that!

My code:

```
aws_env_list="../../../source_files/aws_environments/aws_environments_all.txt"
    with open(aws_env_list, 'r') as aws_envs:
        for line in aws_envs:
        print(line)
```

Each line prints out with a blank line after each entry:

```
company-lab

company-bill

company-stage

company-dlab

company-nonprod

company-prod

company-eng-cis
```

The source file looks like this:

```
company-lab
company-bill
company-stage
company-dlab
company-nonprod
company-prod
company-eng-cis
```

How do I get rid of the blank line after each entry?

Comment: The file contains newlines (`'\n'`) but doesn't remove them when you loop over it. The print function also prints a newline at the end. So you either use `print(line, end='')` to remove the new line from the print function or use `line=line.strip()` to remove the newline from the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has a new line character at the end of each line like:

```
company-lab\n
company-bill\n
company-stage\n
company-dlab\n
company-nonprod\n
company-prod\n
company-eng-cis # not here though this has an EOF (end-of-file) character.
```

So your call to `print(line)` is including these in the print! You can avoid this like:

```
aws_env_list="../../../source_files/aws_environments/aws_environments_all.txt"
with open(aws_env_list, 'r') as aws_envs:
    for line in aws_envs.readlines():
        print(line.strip()) # just strip the \n away!
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to compute with just the text and not the newline character you can strip it away like this:

```
aws_env_list="../../../source_files/aws_environments/aws_environments_all.txt"
with open(aws_env_list, 'r') as aws_envs:
    for line in aws_envs.readlines(): 
        line = line.strip() # You can strip it here and reassign it to the same variable
        # Now all your previous code with the variable 'line' will work as expected
        print(line) # no need to strip again
        do_computations(line) # you can pass it to functions without worry
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a file line-by-line using:

```
for line in aws_envs:
```

The value of `line` includes the end-of-line character...and the `print` command, by default, *adds* an end-of-line character to your output.  You can suppress that by setting the `end` parameter to an empty value.  Compare:

```
>>> print('one');print('two')
one
two
```

Vs:

```
>>> print('one', end='');print('two')
onetwo
```